# Hiding function on nested class

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Public Class Class1

Private names As List(Of String)
Private _class2 As New Class2

Public Sub AddName(ByVal name As String)
    names.Add(name)
    _class2.Add()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property AddAge(ByVal name As String) As Class2
    Get
        _class2.index = names.IndexOf(name)
        Return _class2
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    names.Clear()
    _class2.Clear()
End Sub

Public Class Class2

    Private _age As List(Of Integer)
    Protected Friend index As Integer

    Public Property Age() As Integer
        Get
            Return _age(index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _age(index) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Add()
        _age.Add(0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear()
        _age.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
End Class
```

How can I hide ,Sub Clear and Sub Add on class2, so they'll only be visible on class1, like;

```
Public Sub Clear()
    names.Clear()
    _class2.Clear() '<<<<<<<
End Sub
```

I want they do not be visible on Sub Main(), like they are below.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim person As New Class1

    person.AddAge("kid").Clear() '<<<<<<
    person.AddAge("kid").Add() '<<<<<<

End Sub
```

If I put Protected, I class1 cannot access it. If I put Protected Friend, Sub Main() can still access them. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Trust in .NET follows assembly boundaries.  If you get two classes in one assembly then there are two programmers that know how to find each other if there's a problem.  The only way to get what you want is to put these classes in a separate class library project.  Which then lets you use Friend.  And whomever writes that Main method doesn't have to be friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used  -Hans Passant- comment.

"Trust in .NET follows assembly boundaries. If you get two classes in one assembly then there are two programmers that know how to find each other if there's a problem. The only way to get what you want is to put these classes in a separate class library project. Which then lets you use Friend. And whomever writes that Main method doesn't have to be friendly."